# Open emacs with a horizontal split

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs

When opening emacs with two files `$ emacs a.txt b.txt`, the window splits vertically.

I need to have a horizontal split instead.   Is there a variable that controls this behavior or is there a hook where I can override the one behavior without changing other behaviors as well?

I've looked at related questions on StackOverflow but they had a different focus and their answers weren't directly applicable:

- OP wants to *delete* the other windows when opening files:  [How do I prevent emacs from horizontally splitting the screen when opening multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144729)
- OP wants to *globally* affect all functions that split windows and the answer involves tricking the split algorithm into thinking there is not enough space fo a vertical split: [Setting Emacs Split to Horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081577/setting-emacs-split-to-horizontal) and the same applies for:
  [Open new Emacs buffer using vertical splitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389147)

I would like to find the specific code runs when emacs is opened and change just the one call to `(split-window-vertically)`.

In case it matters, I'm using GNU Emacs 24.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific code to open files from the command line is in `startup.el`.  The function is `command-line-1` and it calls `find-file-other-window` (in two different places).

You should be able to do something like this in your .emacs, but I'm not sure about the details:

```
(defadvice find-file-other-window (before split (file &optional wildcards))
  (if <during command line processing>
      (split-window-horizontally)))
(ad-activate 'find-file-other-window)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
emacs -Q a.txt -eval "(split-window-horizontally)" -eval "(find-file \"b.txt\")"
```

Maybe set some font too, for example Liberation Mono-18:

```
emacs -Q a.txt -eval "(split-window-horizontally)" -eval "(find-file \"b.txt\")" --font 'Liberation Mono-18'
```

Without option -Q load your init-file also.

Well, just for completeness, when at a file already: C-x 3

Answer (score 0):

There's an option to [transpose](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/transpose-frame.el)
vertical/horizontal split. Very convenient and fun.